# PHP file not displaying anything after checking it several times

Tags: php, for-loop

So I have been asked to insert rows to this database using a html form. Here's the code of the form:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="header1">
  <h1>Donar d'alta un client</h1>
</div>
<hr>
<form action="alta.php" method="post">
    Numero: <input type="text" name="cnumero" /><br>
    Nom: <input type="text" name="cnom" /><br>
    Adreca: <input type="text" name="cadreca" /><br>
    Codi Postal: <input type="text" name="ccp" /><br>
    Poblacio: <input type="text" name="cpob" /><br>
    Dni: <input type="text" name="cdni" /><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="cemail" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Afegeix" />
</form>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

That's a normal form, nothing special, it works.
Now here it comes the problem. In the file alta.php, I have the PHP code to insert all this information in a row of this existing table. The table is called CLIENT and it has all this parameters and 3 more which have to be NULL when you add a new row. Here's the code of alta.php :

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include 'vars.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$numero= $_POST['cnumero'];
$nom= $_POST['cnom'];
$adreca= $_POST['cadreca'];
$codi_postal= $_POST['ccp'];
$poblacio= $_POST['cpoblacio'];
$dni= $_POST['cdni'];
$email= $_POST['cemail'];

$conn = oci_connect('u*******', 'u*******', '********');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['No em connectat a la BD'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO client 
                                    (client_num, client_nom, client_adreca, client_codi_postal, client_poblacio, client_dni, client_email)
                          VALUES
                                    (:client_num, :client_nom, :client_adreca, client_codi_postal, :client_poblacio, :client_dni, :client_email)");

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":client_num", $numero);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":client_nom", $nom);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":client_adreca", $adreca);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":client_codi_postal", $codi_postal);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":client_poblacio", $poblacio);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":client_dni", $dni);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":client_email", $email);


    $r = oci_execute($stid);


    if ($r) { echo 'Client afegit correctament.'; }
    if (!$r){ echo 'Hi ha hagut un error.'; }

    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);   
?>
        <br><br><br>
        <div id="tornar">
            <li><a href="index2.html">Tornar a l'inici</a></li>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is my browser keeps saying there's an 'Internal Server Error'. So apparently there's a piece of this code which doesn't work. Could you guys help me a bit? I've spent way too much time thinking about it and I can't see what's wrong.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `Internal server error` means _go check your error log_!  it also means you need to enable `display_errors`.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Are you running/testing this on a remote server? If so, best practice is to edit it on your own computer, debug it there, and then deploy.

Comment: Do NOT enable `display_errors` on productive servers. This would expose internal information to the users.

Comment: @Eyal Alsheich vars.php is in the file because the teacher told me it had to be there. This can't be the error.

Comment: have you looked in the file? is it even in the correct path?

Comment: Edited the question with all the updates I have done. Error is still the same. Internal Server Error when I finish filling the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `input names` in your form don't match what you are trying to get from `$_POST` in your PHP code.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I changed that to the actual input names to the ones I have in the php file but it still says Internal Server Error. I Typed what Michael Berkowsk about the errors, but still nothing happens. I get the same error and no description.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you don't have the oracle libraries installed correctly. Generally with issues like this, I will put `echo 'it works' && exit;` at numerous places in the code until it stops working. I then know that is the problem function.

Error log is also a possibility , but I've often found in the past that there is nothing in the logs.

Comment: Thanks for that. But the problem is I can't see the output. Whenever I fill the form and it redirects me to alta.php it gives me that error. I don't know how can I test this to know from what point it doesn't work.